# Problema al abrir aplicacion en Yii2

Tags: xampp, yii2

Estoy presentando el siguiente problema y es que al momento de abrir mi aplicacion de Yii2, la cargo en mi navegador de la siguiente manera **http://localhost/basic/web/** y me sale el siguiente error `Fatal error: Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php on line 77`

Estoy utilizando Xampp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente cambiando la linea a la que hace referencia el error de **Object** a **BaseObject** y me sale el siguiente error `Fatal error: Cannot declare class yii\base\BaseObject, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php on line 77`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También realice el refactor de Object.php a BaseObject y me arroja el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logre realizar `composer update` y cuando voy a abrir la aplicacion me sale el siguiente error **Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mi version de php es 7.2.3

Comment: No me sale el error cuando creo un nuevo proyecto, me aparece este error cuando intento abrir el proyecto sobre el cual estoy trabajando

Comment: No lo probe aun, ya no me sale la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Te recomiendo que pruebes primero con un composer update  `composer
>   update`  :)

A partir de la version de PHP_7.2 (creo) Object se ha combertido en palabra reservada y el error que te aparece es normal , Yii soluciono esto a partir de la version de Yii2.0.13,

Entonces si queires resolver tu problema  te sugiero que mires la docuemtacion de como migrar esto .

[Aqui la documentacion](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.13/framework/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-from-yii-2012)

Para resumir vas a tener que hacer un bonito refactor  yii/base/Object.php y cambiarlo a yii/base/BaseObject.php.

Comment: Revisa nuevamente la pregunta y mira el  error que me sale al realizar el refactor

Comment: y si haces composer update ?

Comment: Si realice composer update pero mira el error que me sale ahora Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved si quieres revisa la pregunta nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar la versión de Yii2 con Apache como servidor web necesita realizar la siguiente configuración en el archivo httpd.conf

```
# Set document root to be "basic/web"
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\web"

<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\web">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # if $showScriptName is false in UrlManager, do not allow accessing URLs with script name
    RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]

    # ...other settings...
</Directory>
```

Una vez hecho esta configuración debe reiniciar XAMPP. Puede ver más detalle sobre estas recomendaciones en la [documentación oficial](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md)

Comment: No me funciono, sigue igual